# It just got the 1.5.0 version automatically and on iOS it is not able to read from .env file

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

It just got the 1.5.0 version automatically and on iOS it is not able to read from .env file.

i try this
cp "${PROJECT_DIR}/../.env.development" "${PROJECT_DIR}/../.env" in xcode build pre action but i am unable to run my project in development.